# Qual é a necessidade dessa variável nesse laço?

Tags: python

Eu fiz um simples programa em Python que renomeia com um número aleatório todos os arquivos da pasta em que o arquivo do programa está. Após algumas tentativas e erros, eu percebi em alguns exemplos da internet que no laço que fazia a "leitura" dos arquivos tinha uma variável a mais do que o laço que eu tinha pensado. Alguém pode me dizer a utilidade dele?

Nesse caso aqui está com a variável `x`

```
import os, random
dirs = os.listdir(".")

for x, file in enumerate(dirs):    
    src = file
    newName = str(random.randint(1, 1000000))
    os.rename(src, newName)
```

Porém quando eu retiro essa variável...

```
import os, random
dirs = os.listdir(".")

for file in enumerate(dirs):    
    src = file
    newName = str(random.randint(1, 1000000))
    os.rename(src, newName)
```

... dá o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) retorna um objeto iterável.
Quando você faz o `enumerate` de uma lista, ao percorrer essa lista você acessa [tuplas](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_tuples.htm) com 2 elementos.

No seu segundo código, a variável de loop `file` é algo do formato `(index, file_name)`, e como o método `rename` recebe uma string como primeiro parâmetro, o erro ocorre, pois você está passando um objeto tipo tupla e não tipo string.

No primeiro código, ao fazer a decomposição

```
for x, file in enumerate(dirs)
```

A primeira variável `x` recebe o primeiro elemento da tupla ( `index` ) e a variável `file` recebe o segundo elemento ( `file_name` ) da tupla gerada pelo método `enumerate`.

Como em nenhum momento você utiliza a variável `x`, não é necessário o método `enumerate`, o método `os.listdir` já retorna uma lista iterável.

```
import os, random
dirs = os.listdir(".")

for file in dirs:    
    src = file
    newName = str(random.randint(1, 1000000))
    os.rename(src, newName)
```